# Irreducible representations of nonabelian group generated by $3$ elements

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

My question is rather commonplace, but nevertheless I'd like to discribe irreducible representations of the so called Heisenberg group (I suppose this one is just a special case of Heisenberg group). This group $H_N$ is generated by three elements $a,b,k$ such that $[a,b]=k$, $[a,k]=[b,k]=e$ and also $a^N=b^N=k^N=e$.
Let's denote $T:H_N\longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ some irreducible representation. It is easy to see that $T(k)$ is in the center of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ hence it acts by some scalar $s$, such that $s^N=1$. In the first case we assume that $s=1$ then we get a pair of operators $T(a)$ and $T(b)$ which commute. We get immediately their common eigenvector and one-dimensional invariant subspace. Could you help me what to do if $T(s)\ne \mathrm{Id}_V$ (i.e. $s\ne 1$)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an irreducible representation where $k$ acts as the scalar $s$, which is, as you noted, and $N$-th root of unity.  You also have $[a,b]=k$, which means (writing $a$ and $b$ instead of $T(a)$ and $T(b)$ for brevity) $ba=sab$ (or, if your convention for commutators is the reverse of mine, $ab=sba$, in which case you should change $s$ to $s^{-1}$ in what follows).  This implies that, if $x$ is an eigenvector of $b$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $ax$ is also an eigenvalue of $b$ with eigenvalue $s\lambda$.  So all $n$ of the numbers $s^n\lambda$ (for $0\leq n<N$) are eigenvalues of $b$, and their eigenvectors $a^nx$ are cyclically permuted by $a$.  This observation, along with the fact that $\lambda$ is also an $N$-th root of unity, should be enough to let you completely describe the representation.